# Let $A\in M_n(C)$ satisfy $||Ax||\leq ||x||$ for all $x\in C^n$. Then prove that if $k \in C$ such that $|k|>1$, then $A-kI$ is invertible.

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

> Let $A\in M_n(C)$ satisfy $||Ax||\leq ||x||$ for all $x\in C^n$. Then
>   prove that if $k \in C$ such that $|k|>1$, then $A-kI$ is invertible.

suppose $(A-kI)(x)=0$

I want to show $x=0$

I am really unable to think of a way to connect this with $||Ax||\leq ||x||$

Please help.

Comment: If $(A - kI)(x) = 0$, then $Ax = kx$. What happens if you take the norm of both sides?

Comment: Then I have $||Ax||=||kx|| = |k|.||x|| < ||x||$ but this is already true from given condition so how does it help me

Comment: It's not already true. If $|k| \cdot \|x\| \le \|x\|$, then either $|k| \le 1$ or $\|x\| = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much